# How to get value of specific property from list?

Tags: c#, .net, linq, generic-list

I have the following class:

```
public class ClassA
{
   public string Property1 { get; set; }
   public string Property2 { get; set; }
   public string Property3 { get; set; }
}
```

There are instances of the class in a `List<ClassA>`.  How do I get a `List<string>` of values for `Property2` from all classes?

Comment: Did any of the answers below solve your problem?

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`Linq.Select`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.linq.enumerable.select(v=vs.110).aspx) to do so:

```
List<ClassA> list = new List<ClassA>
{
    new ClassA { Property2 = "value 1"},
    new ClassA { Property2 = "value 2"},
};

//This is method syntax
var result = list.Select(item => item.Property2).ToList();

//This is query syntax
var result = (from item in list
             select item.Property2).ToList();
```

*Keep not that the `ToList()` are not a must and are here just for ease in using this code example*

The `Select` basically boils down to something similar to:

```
List<string> response = new List<string>();
foreach(var item in list)
{
    response.Add(item.Property2);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

You can use [Select](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb548891(v=vs.100).aspx)

```
var properties = listOfA.Select(x=>x.Property2);
```

or through the [query syntax](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb397927.aspx):

```
    var list = new List<ClassA>();

    var properties = from item in list
                     select item.Property2
```

Answer (score 0):

To change from the `Select(...).ToList()` "pattern" you can also use the existing method inside `List<T>` which do the job, namely [`ConvertAll`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/73fe8cwf(v=vs.110).aspx) using nearly the same exact code.

```
// source is your List<ClassA>
var result = source.ConvertAll(item => item.Property2);
// result is already a List<string> so no need for extra code
```